# C++ What is the best way of allowing moving data out of a class member (std::move syntax)

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Imagine that I have a class whose main responsibility is to populate a data container. I would like to move the data out of this class. So I have:

```
class cCreator
{  
public: 
   void generate()
   {
      ///generate the content of data_ and populate it
      ....
      ....
   }

   //variation 1
   std::vector<int>&& getData1()
   {
      return std::move(data_);
   }

   //variation 2
   std::vector<int> getData2()
   {
      return std::move(data_);    
   }
private:
      std::vector<int> data_
};
```

S what is the difference between variation 1 and variation 2 of getData(). What changes when I omit && from the function definition??

Comment: A little comment on the side: Note that since the call to `getData()` destroys the member, you might want to add rvalue ref-qualifiers to the function: `std::vector<int> cCreator::extractData() &&`. That way, you force the caller to provide an rvalue reference for extracting the data, which makes it more explicit that the member is being removed from the object. That is, `obj.extractData()` will no longer compile, but `std::move(obj).extractData()` will.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, no move actually happens in the function itself.  You are just returning an rvalue reference, which allows the original caller to move if needed.  In the second case, the data is actually being moved into a temporary, regardless of how the caller uses the result.

```
cCreator c1, c2;
c1.getData1(); // no move
std::vector<int> v1 = c1.getData1(); // move directly from data_
                                     // into v1.
c2.getData2(); // move to temporary, which isn't used.
std::vector<int> v2 = c2.getData1(); // move from data_ to temporary,
                                     // then move from temporary to v2.
```

Comment: Last case will not necessarily imply a temporary if RVO is done, but the behavior will be what you described

Answer (score 2):

Version 1 is probably a bad idea, things like `f(x.getData())` might be moving or not depending on the signature of `f`. In general we want any `move` to be explicit in the code, so you should at very least have something like:

```
std::vector<int>&& getData() &&
{
  return std::move(data_);
}
```

So that now the move has to be explicit: `f( std::move(x).getData() )`, and you probably want to provide an overload for `const &` just for observing.

Version 2 would be ok if it had another name. In my experience, 99% of the people perceive `getX` as a non-modifying operation. Better call it `releaseData`, which is consistent with the naming of `unique_ptr::release`.

Comment: +1 against getData() naming. Other naming suggestions : moveData, popData, peekData. I never use any "get" function as the intention is always unclear. Best use data() for a const access, and one of these clearer action names for modifying operations.

Comment: @galinette I had the same opinion, then `get(tuple)` happened and that opened a whole lot of doors for `getX` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in this specific case where the container whose data is extracted (moved) is a stl vector, std::swap would be a valid option. So simply supplying:

```
const std::vector<int>& getData() const;
std::vector<int>& getData();
```

woudl enable user to safely extract the data if he so wishes. That might be only viable option if C++11 is not available for some reason.